# Google Analytics 4 export to BigQuery with wrong timestamps (until 22:59h)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I have a data flow configured from GA4 to Bigquery on a daily basis. The problem is that when I query the data, I see that I have data from 23:00 the previous day until 22:59.

I attach an image for clarification:

Does anyone have the same problem, does it only happen to me, how can I fix it?

Tx

[Wrong timezone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axeTS.png)

Comment: What reporting time zone is the analytics property configured with?

Comment: Also it is better to include the content from the image content as text in the question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have your property time zone set to UTC+1 (CET or Europe/Madrid maybe?).

BigQuery works with time data in UTC. That's the reason [timestamp_micros()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp_micros) returns a UTC-based timestamp.

You can get the min and max values in the timezone you configured in analytics using `string( timestampvalue, "CET")` (you can use another named timezone like "Europe/Madrid" as well):

```sql
SELECT
   string( min(timestamp_micros(event_timestamp)),"CET" ),
   string( max(timestamp_micros(event_timestamp)), "Europe/Madrid" )
FROM
   `yourproject.dataset.events_20220112` ;
```

Comment: That is correct Iñigo. I will change the property time zone and see what happen into BigQuery. Thanks you!